# Error when pushing branch created from Git

Tags: git, branch, push, commit

I've just created a branch from a commit.

```
git branch my_branch my_commit_hash
```

I don't modify anything then. Now I want to push this branch to the remote repository.

```
git push -u origin my_branch
```

Unfortunately I'm getting this error

```
 ! [remote rejected] my_branch -> my_branch (my_commit_id by ... was not committed by ...)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://repo'
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

I've tagged the commit from which I'm creating the branch. Maybe this causes this error?

Comment: maybe it is a permission issue?

Comment: This looks like a hook that checks whether the commits being pushed are made by a certain person (`was not committed by ...`). Do you have access to the server? Contact the server administrator and check which hooks are active there...

Answer (score 0):

try to do git checkout first,

```
git checkout your_branch
```

or you can do this when creating a branch..

```
git checkout -b your_branch
```

this is shorthand for

```
git branch your_branch
git checkout your_branch
```

then you should be able to do

```
git push origin your_branch
```